# Where is my android folder in java package?

Tags: android

```
import android.content.Intent;
```

I don't see any folder named android in my project, but  I can able to use an Intent class with no errors, how is it possible?

Comment: because thats the android framework.jar

Comment: where the android.jar is located and why it is created and by whom?@tyczj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is `android.jar` in the compile-time classpath that contains stub versions of the Android framework classes. That's why you can use them in your code.

A real Android device then has the actual non-stub implementations in the runtime classpath.

Comment: Treat me like a kid Master

Comment: Which docs u would like me to read it for this?

Comment: Depends on what you want to know. You can find android.jar in your Android Studio Project view under External Libraries.

Comment: U made my day Master

Comment: One last doubt for me

Comment: Gradle is adding the libraries written in Dependency{} to the external library folder, but I haven't added android.jar in my dependencies, But how it got added to external libraries?

Comment: You are applying an Android Gradle Plugin that does it for you.